# no se devuelve los valores del array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

hola amigos me podrian ayudar  ya, probe la conexion y esta bien la petición y  también  solo que en el momento del while  se ejecuta me muestra cual es la fila que agarro en forma de array pero cuando le digo que el valor se ha devuelto para poder encerrarlo en una variable no funciona el valor parece que no se devuelve ya lo prove devolviendo todo el array, también devolviendo por cada uno de su valores y tampoco no se que es lo que estoy de proto ejecutando mal o escribiendo mal, me pueden ayudar.

```
 <?php
   include 'conexion.php';

    session_start();
    $_SESSION ['usu'] = $cedula;

echo $_SESSION ['usu'];
$uno ='1007733197';
$dos ='1412';

$array1  = $row;
$array2  =$row[usuario];
$array3  =$row[cedula];
$array4  =$row[email];
$array5 =$row[contra];
$array6  =$row[movil];


echo '<br>'. $array1;
echo '<br>'.$array2;
echo '<br>'.$array3;
echo '<br>'.$array4;
echo '<br>'.$array5;
echo '<br>'.$array6;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cuentas WHERE cedula = $uno AND contra = $dos";

$peticion = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($peticion) > 0){

 while($row = $peticion->fetch_assoc()){
   echo '<br>'.$array1;
   echo '<br>'.$array2;
   echo '<br>'.$array3;
   echo '<br>'.$array4;
   echo '<br>'.$array5;
   echo '<br>'.$array6;

   return  $row;
  }
}

mysqli_close($conx);
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estas creando unas variables $array1, $array2, etc, a las que les metes el valor de $row, y $row, no existe hasta que entras al while.

Deberías meter esos array1. 2 ,etc dentro del while, o bien, declararlos, pero no darles el valor de $row hasta que entres en el while.

**Solución**

```
$array1  = null;
$array2  = null;
$array3  = null;
$array4  = null;
$array5 =  null;
$array6  = null;

while($row = $peticion->fetch_assoc()){

   $array1  = $row;
   $array2  =$row[usuario];
   $array3  =$row[cedula];
   $array4  =$row[email];
   $array5 =$row[contra];
   $array6  =$row[movil];

   echo '<br>'.$array1;
   echo '<br>'.$array2;
   echo '<br>'.$array3;
   echo '<br>'.$array4;
   echo '<br>'.$array5;
   echo '<br>'.$array6;

   return  $row;
}
```

La variable row es temporal, se crea en el while para trabajar con cada fila que te devuelve la consulta SQL, pero tu, estas intentando acceder a ella antes del while.

**EDIT**
Declara las variables vacias fuera del while, y dentro de este, las actualizas usando la variable $row que contiene cada fila.

De todas formas, aquí tendrás un error, y es que, si tienes mas de 1 fila, estas variables tendrán siempre los datos de la ultima fila obtenida, no todas, si quieres todas tienes que hacer un array bidimensional.

```
$usuario = new Array();

while($row = $peticion->fetch_assoc()){
    $usuario[] = $row;
}
```

Con esas 3 líneas, lo que haces es declarar un array llamado usuario, y dentro del while, cada $row, es decir, cada fila de datos, te los meterá al array, y tendras un array de filas de la tabla, al que podrás acceder así.

```
echo $usuario[0];//Para que te devuelva toda la primera fila

echo $usuario[0]['usuario']; //Para que te devuelva el primer usuario
```

Cambia el 0 para cambiar entre filas y asi tendras los datos de toda la tabla en un array, lo que tu querías hacer te iba a sobreescribir todos los datos y solo ibas a tener disponible los ultimos de la tabla al finalizar el while.

Comment: eso funciona pero solo dentro del while, lo que quiero logra es estraer eso valores y poder utilizarlos en otra secuencia o archivo.

Comment: Pues inicializa los valores fuera del while en null y dentro del while lo dejas como está en mi ejemplo, pero $row solo existe dentro del while. Declara las variables fuera del while y las rellenas dentro. Edito mi respuesta para que lo veas mas claro.

Answer (score 0):

te explico lo que esta pasando:

Tienes esta parte de código en la cabecera, y antes de hacer tu consulta `SQL`:

```
$array1  = $row;
$array2  =$row[usuario];
$array3  =$row[cedula];
$array4  =$row[email];
$array5 =$row[contra];
$array6  =$row[movil];
```

Que ocurre? que `$row`, y todos los `$row[...]` no valen nada.

Por lo tanto tus variables `$arrayX` no valdran nada.

Por ultimo cuando haces tu consulta:

```
while($row = $peticion->fetch_assoc()){
   echo '<br>'.$array1;
   echo '<br>'.$array2;
   echo '<br>'.$array3;
   echo '<br>'.$array4;
   echo '<br>'.$array5;
   echo '<br>'.$array6;

   return  $row;
  }
```

Haces el `echo` de estas variables, que no tienen valor, debes asignarle el valor dentro del `while`. Algo como esto:

```
$array1 = $row[0];
```

ó

```
$array1 = $row['usuario'];
```

El indice de `$row` puede ser numérico o textual, esto depende del método de `fetch` que uses.

En tu caso es este ultimo.

Y para terminar el `return` no se muy bien para que lo uses, pero aquí y en este contexto no hace nada.

---

**EDITO POR TU COMENTARIO**

Para poder enviar o devolver los resultados de tu consulta, se puede hacer con `return` o `echo`.

Que ocurre?

Primero nos fijaremos en el fragmento de `PHP` que nos muestras, haces varios `echo` y si y un `return`.

Después si desde, por ejemplo, una llamada `AJAX`, llamas a este `PHP`, la respuesta serán todos los `echo` mas el `return`, con lo cual sera mas difícil trabajar con esos datos.

para devolverlo, yo te recomiendo que, borres todos los `echo` uses `json_encode($arr);`

**Ejemplo**

```
//CODIGO ANTERIOR...
while($row = $peticion->fetch_assoc()){  
   echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Esto te devolverá un `array asociativo`, con el que podrás trabajar fácilmente y llenar una tabla o un formulario o lo que sea.

Espero te sirva, suerte

Comment: entonces como podría extraer el contenido de una fila  de my mysql para poder utilizarlo en otro archivo?